# Is there an efficient way to invert a guard value with NestJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, authentication, nestjs

I'm working in a Rest API using NestJS and PassportJS. Actually i have some guards to manage authentication and one of these is the **AuthRequiredGuard**.
This guard allows me to protect endpoints allowing to be activated only with users with a given valid token.

I was wondering if there is any way to using this guards in the inverse mode, for example, for my register endpoint.

```
@UseGuards(!AuthRequiredGuard)
register() {
  console.log('register!');
}
```

I would like to find an efficient way of allowing the registration only if the user is not providing a valid authentication token.

Answer (score 0):

Finally just opted for modifying the strategy to have the reverse effect in the validate method (using passport) and then create another guard using this strategy, hope to find a better way of doing it.